# pipenv updates all dependencies bringing breaking changes

Tags: django, docker, pipenv

I'm having problems with an app that uses Django. Everything is in a docker container, there is a `pipfile` and a `pipfile.lock`. So far, so good.

The problem is when I want to install a new depedency. I open the docker container shell, and I install the dependency with `pipenv install <package-name>`.

After installing the package, pipenv runs a command to update the `pipfile.lock` file and doing so updates all packages to their last version, bringing whit these updates a lot of breaking changes.

I don't understand why is this happening, I have all packages listed in my `pipfile` with `~=`, this is suppose to avoid updating to versions that can break your app.

I'll give you an example, I have this dependency in my `pipfile`: dj-stripe = "~=2.4". But, in the `pipfile.lock` file, after pipenv runs the command `lock`, that depedency is updated to its last version (2.5.1).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're installing it within Docker? A common cause of pipfile.lock  conflicts is installing a package locally instead of within Docker and then when the local environment syncs with Docker it will override your pipfile.lock.

Assuming you're using docker-compose, this is how I'm installing my packages:

`docker-compose exec web pipenv install <package-name>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wjh18, I tried to install the package using that command you share with me and I having the exactly same problem. All packages are being updated to their latest version.

Comment: Are you using docker-compose.yml or just a Dockerfile? That command is if you're using docker-compose. You may have to update the post with whatever relevant files you have and describe how you're using Docker.

Comment: I'm using a docker-compose.yml file. Every time I want to run my project I use the commadn `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what my problem was.

I've been listing the dependencies like this: `~=2.4`, I thought that was indicating not to update to `2.5` or greater, but that's not true, that only tells pipenv not to update to `3` or greater.

In order to stay in `2.4` version, I must specify the last number version, for example: `~=2.4.0`

That way, I'm telling pipenv not to update from `2.4`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Thank you for answering and doing your best to help me @wjh18, I know it seems like you weren't of much help, but I noticed what was happening after cheeking again how all my environment was built and checking all the Docker stuff. You were part of the solution even if it wasn't a direct answer.